# Click button type previous page next page can I use Paging3?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

I want to implement a project that supports offline, but pagination is triggered by buttons, not by sliding to the bottom. How do I use Paging3? Still doesn't work?

I want to implement local paging through the room database and want to get help from the big guy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.